# Gulp not register changes when move scss files into folders

Tags: sass, gulp

When my file structure looks like this, in same folder `gulp watch` is working and register changes

```
├─ styles
   ├── _color.scss
   ├── _mixins.scss
   ├── _layout.scss
   ├── _navigation.scss
   ├── main.scss
```

main.scss

```
@import "colors";
@import "mixins";
@import "navigation";
```

But when I move scss files into folder like this:

[image]

And import it from main file:

```
@import "globals/colors";
@import "globals/mixins";
@import "components/navigation";
```

It's not working, and not register any changes when run gulp watch. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require ('gulp-sass'),
  notify = require('gulp-notify'),
  mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files'),
  filter = require('gulp-filter'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var config = {
 stylesPath: 'assets/styles',
 jsPath: 'assets/scripts',
 bowerDir: 'bower_components'     ,
 outputDir: 'public'
}

gulp.task('js', function() {
 return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles().concat(config.jsPath+'/*'))
  .pipe(filter('**/*.js'))
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.outputDir + '/js'));
});

gulp.task('icons', function() { 
 return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/fonts/**.*') 
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.outputDir + '/fonts')); 
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
 return gulp.src(config.stylesPath + '/main.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    includePaths: [
     config.stylesPath,
     config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
     config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss'
    ]
   }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.outputDir + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch([config.stylesPath + '**/*.scss', config.stylesPath + '**/*.sass', config.stylesPath + '**/*.css'], ['css']);

 gulp.watch([config.jsPath + '**/*.js'], ['js']);

})

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css', 'icons']);
```

So, what is the problem with my project structure, so that `gulp watch` is not working?

Comment: Can you try it without partials in scss file names?

Comment: Shouldn't `config.stylesPath + '**/*.scss'` be `config.stylesPath + '/**/*.scss'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my `gulp.js` file, task watch. I change it to:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch([config.stylesPath + '/**/*.scss', config.stylesPath + '/**/*.sass', config.stylesPath + '/**/*.css'], ['css']);

    gulp.watch([config.jsPath + '**/*.js'], ['js']);

})
```